# Enable follow-mode in dired

Tags: dired, follow-mode

Upon working on org agenda, it's super convenient to employ  `(org-agenda-follow-mode)`

[The Org Manual: Agenda Commands](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Commands.html#Agenda-Commands)

It display the original contents on other window instantly while scrolling around the agenda.

> F (org-agenda-follow-mode)
>    Toggle Follow mode. In Follow mode, as you
>   move point through the agenda buffer, the other window always shows
>   the corresponding location in the Org file. The initial setting for
>   this mode in new agenda buffers can be set with the variable
>   org-agenda-start-with-follow-mode.

When it comes to Dired [Dired - GNU Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html)

You have to invoke `C-o` to achieve the same result.

Is it possible to enable `follow-mode` in Dired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAICS this feature has not yet been realized.

For a start you can use this little minor mode.

```
(define-minor-mode dired-follow-mode
  "Diplay file at point in dired after a move."
  :lighter " dired-f"
  :global t
  (if dired-follow-mode
      (advice-add 'dired-next-line :after (lambda (arg) (dired-display-file)))
    (advice-remove 'dired-next-line (lambda (arg) (dired-display-file)))))
```

Note that there is also a `follow-mode` in Emacs with a different meaning.

Comment: this is super to view images. many thanks.

Comment: Possibly interesting in this context: image-dired.  M-x image-dired in a dired buffer produces thumbnails and allows navigation and display to the previous/next image with SPC/DEL from the thumbnail buffer and much more.